# Google Earth Engine: trying to get an array of values from a feature collection but I'm getting an empty array out

Tags: google-earth-engine

I have a point feature which I've used to reduce values from an image collection.

The values are obtained as a new feature's property by mapping over the images with this code (specifically getting ndvi values):

```
var my_vals = images.map(function (img){
    var ndviImg = img.normalizedDifference(['B5', 'B4']);
    return ee.Feature(area, ndviImg.reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.mean(), point)); 
});
```

I need these values to be put into an array so I can do additional calculation on them. However, the function Feature.getArray() returns an empty array.

```
var myArray = my_vals.getArray("nd");
print(my_vals);   // returns "[]"
```

However I know that the values do exist within properties, because if I run the following code I can print out a list of the properties.

```
var myList = my_vals.aggregate_array("nd");
print(myList)   // this prints a list of my values
```

My goal is to do divide one list of these values by another. As far as I am aware I need the values in an array in order to be able to do this (I could not find a way to do this with the object that .aggregate_array() returns).

Does anybody know why this may be, or a better way to be able to get these values in a way I can programatically do math using them?

Apologies for the beginner question here, this is an issue I've been struggling with for a while.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Why `getArray` doesn't work:**

`collection.getArray('x')` is the same as `ee.Array(collection.get('x'))` — that is, it looks up properties of what you call it on. Since your collection does not *itself* have a property named 'nd', there is no data. The `get` family does not operate on the contents of collections.

**What to do instead:**

To get any sort of data out of a collection, use the `reduceColumns` operation; if you need all of them, use `ee.Reducer.toList()` as the reducer.

```
print(my_vals
    .reduceColumns(ee.Reducer.toList(), ['nd'])
    .get('list'));
```

Comment: Thanks Kevin. I see that this process gets a list out. Is there a method to do math on the values of one list based on the values of another? (Essentially I have two equal size lists and would like to divide the contents of list1 by the values of list2).    I could not find a method to do this with list objects, hence trying to get them as arrays.

Comment: @perezoso_estudioso Where did this other list come from? If its origin is also a collection, you might be better off using a _join_ to bring together the elements of the two collections, then map over the result of that to perform the division.

Comment: Kevin, yes the other list is also from a collection, derived in the same manner. Apologies as I should have mentioned this at the start, but my overall aim is to calculate and plot an index whose formula is (values_list1 / values_list2) (where list 2 are control points and list 1 is an area of interest).

Comment: @perezoso_estudioso I reiterate my recommendation of using a join and calculating the division by mapping over the joined features, then. (If you have any trouble with this, please ask a separate question; comment threads are not for this.)